# How often does LocationClient.getLastLocation() get updated?

Tags: java, android, location

I need to know how often the Location object returned from this method is updated and whether it is based on time or distance or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [getLastLocation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#getLastLocation%28%29) documentation it returns the known location.

I think it stores the `LocationClient` stores the location when it's known then returns this value when a call to `getLastLocation` method is called.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I already know all of that. My question is very specific regarding when and how often the system decides to update the location object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it calls automatically. You need to make such code so that it will be called periodically/automatically every after that particular time interval.

For that you need to refer 
                 ***AlarmManager, Service & BroadcastReceiver.*** 
These 3 things will help you to call that getLastLocation() as per the time you set.

Because as far as I know if you think that this method will get called automatically/periodically as user's location gets changes so that is completely wrong. It doesn't work automatically, you need to implement that type of code, then & then only it will be called automatically every after set time interval.

Comment: Yes I know all that already..my question is how does Android system location get updated. To be more specific, where does getLastLocation() get the Location from? And how is that location kept updated ?

Comment: See I already mentioned it in my answer. There is no automatic way to keep getting updated location by this or any other method. You need to do it by code only. Read my answer once again

Comment: And answer of your this question where does getLastLocation gets location from is Read this :  https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html

Comment: Ok I'll try once again, I don't care about the Location that I retreive. I want to know how the android system keeps the Location up to date. It does that for a fact. Read the documentation once again. http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: Of course it is. I need to know that to decide if I want to activate the GPS or use system location. Depends on how often the system location gets updated. I was just wondering if anyone knew this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58469/discussion-between-rit-and-aci89).